# R data.table sum of last N rows in in triangle decreasing contribution by distance

Tags: r, data.table

Firstly apologies for the title of the question, I did not know how to phrase it. Say I have a data table **DT_RET** which has the returns of a stock over some period plus a holding period for a backtest called **N**. E.g. it looks like this:

```
Date          ReturnSinceYesterday        N    
2016-01-01    0.01                        5
2016-01-02    -0.025                      5 
2016-01-03    -0.021                      5
2016-01-04    0.005                       5
...
2016-01-01    0.01                        7
2016-01-02    -0.025                      7 
2016-01-03    -0.021                      7
2016-01-04    0.005                       7
...
```

Now what I want to add to each row, is add a **TotalReturn** field which for some given **N**, gives the return of entering in each of the last **N** days and holding to this day. E.g. if **N** was **5** , and the last **5 returns + 1.0** were **a,b,c,d,e** this would be:

```
((a.b.c.d.e - 1.0) + (b.c.d.e - 1.0) + (c.d.e - 1.0) + (d.e - 1.0) + (e - 1.0))
```

So my question is how can I do this (either with data.table functionality or some other R package).

**EDIT (inc formula fix above):**

As a concrete example (as requested), if **N** was **3** and the input data was:

```
Date          ReturnSinceYesterday        N    
2016-01-01    0.01                        3
2016-01-02    -0.025                      3 
2016-01-03    -0.021                      3
2016-01-04    0.005                       3
```

Then the output would be:

```
Date         ReturnSinceYesterday         N     TotalReturn
2016-01-01    0.01                        3     NA          
2016-01-02    -0.025                      3     NA
2016-01-03    -0.021                      3     -0.1024
2016-01-04    0.005                       3     -0.05181
```

The first two rows have NA because there are not enough prior values for the computation. The third row has a value of **-0.1024** from:

```
a = 1.01
b = 0.975
c = 0.979
TotalReturn = ((a.b.c) -1) + ((b.c) - 1) + (c - 1)
TotalReturn = ((1.01 * 0.975 * 0.979) - 1) + ((0.975 * 0.979) - 1) + (0.979 - 1)
TotalReturn = -0.1024
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you show the expected output based on this input?

Comment: What is `(a.b.c.d.e)`

Comment: @Heroka, expected output has been added

Comment: @akrun by a.b.c.d.e I mean a multiplied by b multiplied by c multiplied by d multiplied by e, where for example a is the 5th previous return + 1.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `RcppRoll` you can do:

```
require(RcppRoll)
DT[,base := 1 + ReturnSinceYesterday]
DT[,TotalReturn := rowSums(sapply(seq_len(N), function(i) roll_prodr(base,i)-1))]
```

which results in:

```
> DT
         Date ReturnSinceYesterday N  base TotalReturn
1: 2016-01-01                0.010 3 1.010          NA
2: 2016-01-02               -0.025 3 0.975          NA
3: 2016-01-03               -0.021 3 0.979 -0.10240475
4: 2016-01-04                0.005 3 1.005 -0.05180738
5: 2016-01-05                0.100 3 1.100  0.28778450
```

Why? The critical part is:

```
> DT[, sapply(seq_len(3), function(i) roll_prodr(base,i)-1)]
       [,1]      [,2]        [,3]
[1,]  0.010        NA          NA
[2,] -0.025 -0.015250          NA
[3,] -0.021 -0.045475 -0.03592975
[4,]  0.005 -0.016105 -0.04070238
[5,]  0.100  0.105500  0.08228450
```

This gives you a data-table with 
`[,1] = c - 1`, `[,2] = (b.c) -1` and `[,3] = (a.b.c) -1`. As it is a window-function it is dependent on N. So you can use data.tables `by` argument in your original data with it.

Also this is the critical part. If the function gets slow i guess it is because there is a NxM Tables build for each N. Which might lead to computational issues. You could try to implement `((a.b.c) -1) + ((b.c) - 1) + (c - 1)` yourself using `?RcppRoll::rollit`. I guess this would be more efficient

EDIT:
Example with 2 Cases

```
require(data.table)
DT <- fread("Date          ReturnSinceYesterday        N    
2016-01-01    0.01                        3
            2016-01-02    -0.025                      3 
            2016-01-03    -0.021                      3
            2016-01-04    0.005                       2
            2016-01-05    0.1                         2")



require(RcppRoll)
DT[,base := 1 + ReturnSinceYesterday]

DT[, TotalReturn := rowSums(sapply(seq_len(N), function(i) roll_prodr(base,i)-1)), N]
```

RESULT and Data:

```
         Date ReturnSinceYesterday N  base TotalReturn
1: 2016-01-01                0.010 3 1.010          NA
2: 2016-01-02               -0.025 3 0.975          NA
3: 2016-01-03               -0.021 3 0.979  -0.1024048
4: 2016-01-04                0.005 2 1.005          NA
5: 2016-01-05                0.100 2 1.100   0.2055000
```

Comment: Thanks Floo0, this is exactly what I was looking for. My data set is big so it is slow, so I will look into your suggestion of using rollit.

Comment: actually when i run it with multiple N's in the data e.g. 2 and 3, and a by=N, it doesn't seem to work, i have some warnings e.g. Warning messages:
1: In seq_len(N) : first element used of 'length.out' argument
2: In `[.data.table`(DT, , `:=`(TotalReturn, rowSums(DT[, lapply(seq_len(N),  :
  RHS 1 is length 8 (greater than the size (4) of group 1). The last 4 element(s) will be discarded.                .. any idea what's going wrong? Thanks

Comment: and as well as the warnings the contents of the output do not look correct - it just looks like the N=2 case output is repeated for N = 3

Comment: just added an example with 2 cases for N

Comment: now it looks correct, and also is reasonably fast, thanks very much for this comprehensive answer